# How to connect Dlib to a package ? Error “Could not find the required component ‘libdlib’ “

Tags: cmake, ros, dlib

I want to add this package to my workspace(http://wiki.ros.org/ipa_room_segmentation), so I downloaded it and put it into Myworkspace/src. Then I compiled my workspace, an error occurred like this:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libdlib" with any of the following names:
  libdlibConfig.cmake
  libdlib-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "libdlib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"libdlib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"libdlib" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

Then I have tried some others answers, install the dlib followed this page:https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-ubuntu/

But error still there.

It that I need to connect something about the dlib to my src/CMakelist.txt?

Comment: I’m a new learner, so please make ur answer is specific enough for me to understand .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice！ I’ve found a method to crack this nut. All u have to do is using this line:

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-libdlib

PS: if u use another version of ROS, replace the “kinetic”.

This method can solve many problems Which begin with “could not find ...”,u just need to put the missing one after :
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-